# React Big Calendar style previous days to current date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I would like to styles the background of previous days according to the current date.

I'm trying to follow this [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jp1931172w), but I get the error:

> Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

Which is crazy, because it works in the example. Also, there is no information about the `dateCellWrapper` in the docs, which doesn't help much.

Here is the code:

```
const ColoredDateCellWrapper = (children: any, value: any) =>
    React.cloneElement(Children.only(children), {
        style: {
            ...children.style,
            backgroundColor: value < this.state.currentDay ? 'lightgreen' : 'lightblue',
        },
    });

<BigCalendar
    showMultiDayTimes
    localizer={localizer}
    selectable
    selected={this.state.selected}
    onSelectEvent={this.onSelectEvent}
    onSelectSlot={this.onSelectSlot}
    events={this.state.events}
    step={60}
    timeslots={1}
    defaultView='week'
    startAccessor="start"
    endAccessor="end"
    defaultDate={new Date()}
    components={{
        dateCellWrapper: ColoredDateCellWrapper
    }}
/>
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in 1st line of your code:

```
const ColoredDateCellWrapper = (children: any, value: any) =>
```

It should be:

```
const ColoredDateCellWrapper = ({ children: any, value: any }) =>
```

In short you are passing two arguments to `ColoredDateCellWrapper`, but it expects only 1. After destructuring you should get two props.

**Update as asked by OP:**

If you don't want to use destructuring, then you can do it like this:

```
const ColoredDateCellWrapper = (props: any) =>
React.cloneElement(Children.only(props.children), {
    style: {
        ...props.children.style,
        backgroundColor: props.value < this.state.currentDay ? 'lightgreen' : 'lightblue',
    },
});
```

Comment: I am working with typescript, that is why I did like that :x

Comment: @RCohen Look at the curly braces inside paranthesis.

Comment: I added the curly braces just now, and typescript is complaining about the syntax like this `({children: any, value: any})`

Comment: Thank you very much! ^^

Comment: The error is no longer there, but it is not applying the background color :S.

Comment: @RCohen actually, I have never used `BigCalendar`. But still let me take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you! The docs are not very specific about its props, unfortunately :(

Comment: @RCohen can you please share the code of whole file you are working with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190500/discussion-between-rcohen-and-vishal).